# SymPy cannot lambdify Product

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using SymPy 1.0 and Python 2.7. I want to compute the sum of first 100 integer numbers:

This code runs succesfully

```py
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
s = sy.Sum(x[i], (i, 0, 100))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('x'), s, 'numpy')
s_lambda(np.arange(101))
```

And gives `5050` as expected. But when I try to do the same with a `Product` instead of a `Sum`:

```py
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 0, 100))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('x'), s, 'numpy')
s_lambda(np.arange(101))
```

I got a `NameError: global name 'Product' is not defined`
What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround to get what I want?

Edit 1:
And what if I don't know in advance the limit of the `Product`. Let's say something like

```py
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
n = sy.symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 0, n))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify((sy.DeferredVector('x'), n) s.doit(), 'numpy')
s_lambda(np.arange(101), 5)
```

Edit 2:
I'm trying to find a workaround. `NameError: global name 'Product' is not defined` error is given because of this:

```
lambdastr((sy.DeferredVector('x'), n), p)
```

That gives:

```
lambda x,n: (Product(x[i], (i, 0, n)))
```

While for the `Sum` we got a working lambda function:

```
lambda x,n: ((builtins.sum(x[i] for i in range(0, n+1))))
```

At this point the problem revolves around the definition of the `Product` function. According to the manual I can inject via a `dict` my definition of a function

```
def my_prod(a, b):
    # my implementation
    pass

my_fun = {"Product" : my_prod}
f = sy.lambdify((sy.DeferredVector('x'), n), p, modules=['numpy', my_fun])
f([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
```

Problem is, `list indices must be integers, not Symbol` error is raised when I try to use the lambdified function `f`. I guess this is due to `i` that is a symbol while it is supposed to be an integer. I can't understand why it's not passed the actual `integer` before trying to call `my_prod` as it is for the `Sum` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When the limits of the `Product` are known in advance

You could work around the problem by calling `.doit()` to expand the `Product` into its component parts:

```
In [104]: s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, 10)); s
Out[104]: Product(x[i], (i, 1, 10))

In [105]: s.doit()
Out[105]: x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]*x[6]*x[7]*x[8]*x[9]*x[10]
```

---

For example,

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, 10))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('x'), s.doit(), 'numpy')
print(s_lambda(np.arange(11)))
```

prints

```
3628800
```

---

However, if you use `.doit()` with `sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, 100))` then you'll get an arithmetic overflow since `np.arange(101)` has dtype `int32` or `int64` (depending on your OS) and the product `100!`

```
In [109]: math.factorial(100)
Out[109]: 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

is too large be stored in either an `int32` or `int64` array value.

```
In [118]: np.iinfo('int64').max
Out[118]: 9223372036854775807

In [119]: np.iinfo('int64').max < math.factorial(100)
Out[119]: True
```

Thus,

```
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, 100))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('x'), s.doit(), 'numpy')
print(s_lambda(np.arange(101)))
```

raises a

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

and erroneously prints `0`.

---

If you change the input from an array of dtype `int64` to a list of Python `int`s then 
the product can be computed correctly:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, 100))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('x'), s.doit(), 'numpy')
print(s_lambda(np.arange(101).tolist()))
```

prints

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

---

### When the limits of the `Product` are *not* known in advance

The work-around
(AFAICS) becomes more complicated. If you use a debugger to trace the code path
followed when `Sum` is used you'll find that
[`LambdaPrinter._print_Sum`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/lambdarepr.py#L44)
is called to convert `Sum(x[i], (i, 0, n))` to the expression `builtins.sum(x[i] for
i in range(0, n+1))`.

If we add a `_print_Product` method to `NumPyPrinter` (a subclass of `LambdaPrinter`), 
then we can get `lambdify` to successfully convert `Product` into an expression that NumPy can evaluate:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
import numpy as np
import sympy.printing.lambdarepr as SPL

def _print_Product(self, expr):
    loops = (
        'for {i} in range({a}, {b}+1)'.format(
            i=self._print(i),
            a=self._print(a),
            b=self._print(b))
        for i, a, b in expr.limits)
    return '(prod([{function} {loops}]))'.format(
        function=self._print(expr.function),
        loops=' '.join(loops))
SPL.NumPyPrinter._print_Product = _print_Product

x = sy.IndexedBase('x')
i = sy.symbols('i', cls=Idx)
n = sy.symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)
s = sy.Product(x[i], (i, 1, n))
s_lambda = sy.lambdify((sy.DeferredVector('x'), n), s, 'numpy')
print(s_lambda(np.arange(101), 5))
```

prints

```
120
```

Comment: thanks. I should have thought about the 100! that's just a number I want. I just substitute `Sum` with `Product` and expected it to get me something different than an exception. But what if I **DON'T** know in advance the upper limit (see edited question)?

Comment: I've added a workaround for the case when the limits are variable. It tries to mimic the code path followed by `Sum` and simply adds an analogous method for `Product`.

Comment: This `_print_Product` should be added to SymPy itself.