# Lambdify derivative of product in SymPy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

This question is related to the answer given by @unutbu here [SymPy cannot lambdify Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846492/sympy-cannot-lambdify-product)

I'd like to lambdify the derivative of a product. The exception is `global name 'Derivative' is not defined` and I assume is similar to what happened with `Product`, i.e. there's no printer function defined for that. So I started trying to plug-in a custom function:

```
import sympy.printing.lambdarepr as SPL

def _print_Derivative(self, expr):
    # implementation

SPL.NumPyPrinter._print_Derivative = _print_Derivative
```

But I got immediately stuck as the `expr` parameters looks something like `Derivative(Product(x*z[i], (i, 0, _Dummy_4019)), x)`, i.e. also the `Product` (even if correctly calculated and pretty printed) seems not to have a lambda representation. I thought that given the derivative is calculated by SymPy, I just have to take care about the expansion of the product (with a loop), but I'm not sure. Since I don't know enough about SymPy implementation I'm having hard time figuring out how to properly do this.

Comment: Is the variable you are taking the derivative with respect to (I guess `x` in this example) dependent on the product variable? If not you can pull it out as a power. It would be helpful here to see the full expression you are trying to lambdify.